# Java Web Service makes JPA-MySql inserts, but not selects after the insert

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, jpa, hyperlink

I'm using Link JPA with MySQL into a Web Service to select, insert, update and delete data from/to database.

The problem is: the Web Service makes correctly insert, but then it does not retrieve the data correctly. Example:

Table Usuario linked with a Collection of Table Pets:

-- Select how many pets the user X have: 2.

-- Insert 1 more pet into the user X: ok

-- Select how many pets the user X have: 2 too. (This data should be 3)

But, into the data base the data is correct (3): the insert is made correctly

Comment: try flushing after inserting 1 more pet before SELECTing.

Comment: Plz give little bit more info like, Are u doing this in same session? and code which  is inserting and reding back.

Answer (score 0):

In same session  , If you inserting through session object and reading through JPQL then It'll return only 2 record. Flush after inserting than check what you get.